# search in list of objects for all attributes

Tags: .net, c, linq, generics

I have a class called Student which has three attributes

1. Student No
2. Student Name
3. Result

I have created a list of objects and bind to the Grid.

I have a textbox to search and the grid should be filtered based on the text entered.

I would like to know how to write a code in generics with linq to search all the attributes of list of objects

Comment: Have you considered formatting the data as JSON and search on that structure?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create an extension to search in the properties of an object.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool HasPropertyWithFilter(this object obj, string filter)
    {
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var val = prop.GetValue(obj);
            var str = (val ?? new object()).ToString();
            if (str.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

then you can use it anywhere like this...

```
string filterStr = "N2"; // could be Textbox.Text

var filteredList = 
    list.Where (o => o.HasPropertyWithFilter(filterStr));
```

This is a first scratch, there could be situations where you should be more prepared (for example if the property has an indexer, e.g. `obj.Item[3]`)